# In App Purchase not working after it has been approved

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

as the title says it's a question about my new released app which included one In App Purchase. When I tested the Purchase on the app which I downloaded from AppStore I got no Alert that the Purchase was successful. First a alert View with "Would you like to buy... for 0.99$" came up, I proceeded with Buy. Then I had to type in my mail and password and clicked continue. Then nothing. No Alert that it was successful or something. I also programmed a Indicator that stopped after the second Alert View after few seconds.

I hope it's Apple fault and hopefully it's only a delay.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you really need to add some example code. Otherwise nobody can tell whats going on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities :

1) It's a bug from Apple that will be solved in 4 to 48 hours. 
Many people have the same problem, just check at the Apple developper forum (for example : https://devforums.apple.com/message/459152#459152).

2) You didn't check at information in the app store before asking the purchase of the product. It seems people have a bug after their release because of this. It's absolutely mandatory to ask for information of an in-app purchase before buying it even if you know the price of the product and don't need to check it online.

Comment: Just so signal that I've edited my post. It can also be a problem from your side

Comment: check my posted code. But I've tested it several times before submitting it to iTunes.