# Still Relevant? In App Purchases not working when in store but do in sandbox

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've developed an app that works great in sandbox mode for subscriptions. However when I deploy to app store it doesn't work.

It seems like there is already a lot of information on this, but I can't see any up to date information on the topic like:

[In App Purchase not working after it has been approved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359625/in-app-purchase-not-working-after-it-has-been-approved?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I am having people buy the app and are leaving bad reviews because it doesn't work.

Comment: What happens when you try to purchase a product?

Comment: @AdeelMiraj it errors out and I get a cannot connect to iTunes store error.

Comment: @Dan my suggestion is please create Ad-Hoc provision profile with same identifier and check step by step flow in your xCode device console using NSLog.

Comment: What error do you get? May we see the relevant code you have? Are there any on-device logs that can indicate what the problem might be?